# EmberJS: update model just after request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using EmberJS 1.13.1 with EmberData 1.13.5.

I have some model with field `url`.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  imageUrl: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  options: DS.attr(),
  published: DS.attr('boolean'),
  thumbnailUrl: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And url in this field is relative, smth like `/media/picture.png`. I need to add host-part to this adsress.

For example, I have

***/media/picture.png***

but want to change it to

***http://example.com/media/picture.png***

But items of current model can be added to store in different ways, so the best will be update this field just after it have been added to the store. Is it possible? Maybe add some hook somewhere?

Comment: Show some examples, because it's hard to understand what you exactly need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create computed property which would return host + url, like that:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  fullURL: Ember.computed('url', function() {
    return 'http://example.com' + this.get('url');
  })
});
```

Comment: Thx, man. Didn't know that computed properties are allowed in models.